# tablayout not inflate in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-inflate

i want use tablayout and viewpager in recyclerview item but when android framework want to inflate my layout i get this error:

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating  class <unknown>`

my layout :

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

i use compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' and my recyclerview is in a Fragment and my actvity is extended by AppCompatActivity

my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'




android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.gallery.main"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 3906
    versionName "3.9.0.6"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.liulishuo.filedownloader:library:0.3.2'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile project(':utils')
}
```

Comment: have you used the theme for all activities different or same

Comment: i use same theme for all activities

Comment: could you post your app bulid.gradle

Comment: @ Er. Arjun saini of course

Answer (score 0):

**Add this dependency in your bulid.gradle also**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```